# Ler valor input type file dúvida

Tags: javascript, jquery

Uma dúvida, porquê isso trabalha:

```
$("input[type='file']")[0].files[0]
```

e isso não?

```
$("input[type='file']").files[0] // TypeError: $(...).files is undefined
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Com o Wallace respondeu, ele retorna um [jQuery Object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). Dessa forma, você está acessando o primeiro ( e provavelmente único, no seu caso ) elemento DOM que retornou do objeto.

Você pode acessar um elemento, da seguinte forma:

```
$("input[type='file']")[0]
```

ou

```
$("input[type='file']").get(0)
```

Há também a função [.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/), que retornará o primeiro DOM element do objeto retornado pelo seletor:

```
$("input[type='file']").first()
```

OBS: A função .first() criará um novo jQuery Object com o primeiro elemento.

@edit

Conforme a dica comentada pelo [Guilherme Lautert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14213/guilherme-lautert), também pode acessar um índice através do seletor [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
$("input[type='file']:eq(0)")
```

Comment: também pode se usar `$("input[type='file']:eq(0)")`.

Comment: Obrigado pelo lembrete! Adicionado à resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Quando você faz isso `$("input[type='file']")[0]`, você está acessando o objeto `HTMLInputElement`, que é nativo do javascript.

Nesse elemento, existe a propriedade `files`.

Exemplo:

```
HTMLInputElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('files'); // true
```

Já no caso do `$("input[type='file']")` você está retornando a instância o objeto do `jQuery`, o qual não possui essa propriedade.

Answer (score 4):

Por que o JQuery irá buscar por **Uma** ou **+** ocorrências de `input[type='file']` , logo irá listar os resultados num *Objeto* pelas chaves `([0][1][2],etc)`.

Comment: Na verdade não é bem isso. Se existisse um objeto com capturado pelo jQuery, não existiria a propriedade `files` da mesma forma.

Comment: Sim, você apresentou de fato muito mais completo. Mas minha explicação ainda faz sentido, porem, hiper simplificado, certo?

Comment: Não, não. O problema não é a quantidade de resultados. O problema é o objeto que está sendo retornado. É isso que quis apresentar na minha questão. Um retorna `object` (que é o jQuery) e outro é retornado o `HTMLInputElement`, que é o `input file` independente de jQuery (é nativo do javascript). A sua resposta leva a entender que o problema é o jQuery ter retornado mais de um elemento, e isso não é a verdade. Ele poderia retornar até 100. Se usava o `[0]` na frente sempre retornar o HTMLInputElement

Comment: Foi por isso que dei o -1, porque não responde à pergunta

Comment: Ótimo! Obrigado, acho que ficou muito mais claro agora.

Comment: Sim, de boa. Estava mais preocupado em entender do que com isso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29779/discussion-between-thelimarenan-and-wallace-maxters).

Answer (score 4):

Basicamente a mesma resposta do Wallace, no entanto vou explicar de outra maneira.

O `.files` é uma propriedade nativa da API DOM do JavaScript, sendo assim ele será acessível apenas no quando usar `document.getElementById` e `document.querySelector`, por exemplo:

```
document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files
```

Quando você faz isto:

```
$("input[type=file]")[0] //ou .get(0)
```

Você transforma (extrai) um objeto para [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction), como se tive-se pegado com `document.querySelector`, fazendo o `.files` ficar acessível.

Então `.files` só seria acessível assim `$(...).files` se existi-se esta propriedade no jQuery.

> **Nota:** `document.getElementsByName`, `document.getElementsByTagName` e `document.querySelectAll` retorna objetos `arrays` então `.files` só estará disponível se você acessar um dos items deste `array`.

Existe uma maneira de fazer isto ser acessível, através do `jQuery.fn.` do jQuery, seria assim:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    "files": function() {
         var el    = this.get(0);
         var files = el ? el.files : false;
         return files ? files : [];
    }
});
```

E usa-lo deve ser algo como:

```
console.log($("input[type=file]").files());
```

Note que ele vai retornar uma `array` com os arquivos selecionados e apenas do primeiro elemento da lista do "objeto jQuery".